# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null main

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, google-sheets-formula, typeerror

Im new to coding and im trying to eliminate choices in google forms without Add-ons etc. but i keep getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
> main   @ Kod.gs:11

```
var labels = wsData.getRange(1,1,1,wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: How did you define `wsData`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71631629/1595451